# How can I use a Keyboard Shortcut to tag files?

Tags: keyboard, finder-tag

Short of using a script, how can I create a keyboard shortcut to tag files. I used to use Quickeys to do that which worked well but they stopped supporting the program and I moved to Keyboard Maestro. I've yet to figure out an easy way to do that with that program.

Ideally, I'd like to do this without a script but I'm not sure it can be done. Any ideas?

Comment: Does `⌘`+`i` on a file and then `⇥ tab`,  `⇥ tab` do the trick for you? (You have to have "Full Keyboard Access" enabled for all controls)

Comment: Awesome! I created a macro using this tip and it works great! I will post the macro in answer to my own question go give other users a visual.

Answer (score 1):

Using the tip mentioned above, I created this macro using Keyboard Maestro and it works great! One caveat: you can't use the same macro to undo the red tag. You'd have to create another one for that. If you do use it again, you'll see that it adds an orange tag.

[image]